# Spring Boot Upgrade Redis - Null key returned for cache operation

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis, spring-data-redis, jedis

After the spring 3.x upgrade Redis Cache gives

```
Null key returned for cache operation
```

**spring-boot version: 3.2.2**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
  <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

**Cachable Method:**

```
@Cacheable(value = "user", key = "#username", unless = "#result == null")
public String findUsername(String username) {
    ...
}
```

but if I use **key = "#a0"** instead of **key = "#username"**, the problem is solved.

```
@Cacheable(value = "user", key = "#a0", unless = "#result == null")
public String findUsername(String username) {
    ...
}
```

There was no need to do it this way in the previous version.
**My previous versions:**

```
spring-boot version: 2.7.4
redis.clients jedis version :3.9.0
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spel is impacted in the 3.1 to 3.2 upgrade, you need to pass extra flag to maven compiler to preserve parameter name discovery

Please check

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.2-Release-Notes#parameter-name-discovery

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x#parameter-name-retention

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <parameters>true</parameters>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is detail in the question at the link [Intellij Idea "-parameters to the Additional command line parameters" - Spring Boot 3.x Parameter Name Retention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78067909/14686302).

Another issue related to this problem is;
[Spring Boot 3.x Parameter Name Retention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78037016/14686302)