# Spring Boot 3.x Parameter Name Retention

Tags: spring, spring-boot

To store the Parameter Name, we now have to pass the "-parameters" flag to compiler, starting from the Spring Boot 3.x version. Why is there such a requirement?

Spring made an explanation for this, but I couldn't fully understand the situation. Won't it be difficult to pass "-parameters" from a management perspective?

[Parameter Name Retention](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x#parameter-name-retention)

Comment: Why would it be hard to do `-parameter` if you use Spring Boot and use that as a parent that is already done for you (no  hassle) and else it is 1 line of xml in your maven pom (or gradle build file). Not sure what is hard about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find reason of deprecation and removal in 6.1 in the corresponding PR and issue in Spring github

PR of deprecation : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/29531
Issue for removal : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29559

The main goal was to remove this for native image support without the need to do additional configuration to make it work.