# Intellij Idea "-parameters to the Additional command line parameters" - Spring Boot 3.x Parameter Name Retention

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

To store the Parameter Name, we now have to pass the "-parameters" flag to compiler, starting from the Spring Boot 3.x version.

When Intellij Idea adds "-parameters" to the "**Additional command line parameters**" section and Rebuild, the parameters are processed. However, after each maven reload process, **it is necessary to remove the modules from** the "**Override copiler parameters per-module**" section shown in the picture and rebuild them again. In other cases, the parameters are not reflected in the compiler and this takes time for me to remove and re-build each time from the "**Override copiler parameters per-module**" section. Is there an easier way to set this up?

**My project structure**

```
authorization-app
authorization-bom
authorization-parent
authorization-rest
authorization-data
```

Maven plugin for **parameters** to **authorization-app**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <parameters>true</parameters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image: File - Build,Execution,Deployment - Java Compiler]

Comment: Add it to the maven compiler settings, although afaik the Spring boot 3 parent already does this. So if you haven't overridden that it should work as is.

Comment: I have already added it to maven compiler settings, but I need to add "-parameters" to the compiler to run it locally (isn't this correct?). Even though I added it to maven compiler settings, without doing it as I mentioned in the question, the project gives the "Null key returned for cache operation" error when starting in Intellij-idea.

Comment: If properly imported Intellij will copy the parameters or delegate the building to maven.

Comment: So when I run it locally, do I need to specify it to both maven and compiler?

Comment: Neither should be needed as the maven-compiler by Spring boot is already configured with `<parameters>true</parameters>`. You shouldn't have a `maven-compiler-plugin` in your pom.

Comment: I added the project structure and maven plugin in the question I asked. Can you check this?

Comment: You don't need the maven plugin as mentioned before (please read) if you are using the `spring-boot-starter-parent` as a parent.

Comment: My project is a microservice project. I show the framework I created as a parent in my microservice project. My framework uses spring-boot-starter-parent plugin, normally I never added a maven plugin, I just passed "-parameter" to the compiler in Intellij idea, but if I don't do it as I mentioned in the question, I encounter problems.